# Different date value retrieved from google sheet in Apps Script V8 and Legacy

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8, duration

I have this very simple 4 lines of code to retrieve a duration value in google sheet from Google Apps Script. The sheet is blank and has this only value for this test.

[image: google sheet - one cell value only]

```
function myFunction() {
  var my_ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var my_sh = my_ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var my_value = my_sh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  console.log(my_value);
}
```

When I run this in the new runtime V8, I got the good duration of 5 minutes (with bad GMT but I don't use this). But with the current bug on V8 where we can't use the console to develop arrays and object, I downgraded the script to Apps script Legacy, and when I execute the exact same code (I mean I don't do anything but downgrading the environment with the Run menu), then I got the good GMT but the wrong duration! I got 55 minutes and 39 seconds instead of 5 minutes!
I checked the time zone in apps script V8, apps script legacy and google sheet, it's the same every where, "GMT+01:00 Paris".

Even stranger: this test is actualy performed from a copy of an original file created on august 2019. In the original file I got the opposite behavior. I got the good value with apps script legacy, but with runtime V8 I got a different value (I got 23:14:21 instead of 00:05:00).

Does anyone else encounter this behaviors? Do you know how to run apps script legacy on new files without these problems? Thanks.

[image: google sheet]
[image: google apps script V8 vs Legacy]

Comment: Did you ask this question before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I noticed that we had this issue only in the case we upgrade to V8 on a file that has was created before V8 was published (and vice versa). So to avoid this, if I have an old file where I want to upgrade apps scripts to V8, I copy the file first, and in the new file (so a recent one when V8 already exists), then I don't encounter the problem...

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()) instead :

```
var my_value = my_sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
```

and then, based on this value, you can construct a date object of your preference.

Comment: This is the workaround I will do if there is no other option. For this post I made an example with 4 lines of code and one cell to retrieve, but actualy I have dozen of google sheets with scripts with hundreds of lines, so with the V8 console bug if I have to downgrade all my scripts and I encounter this problem everywhere it's days of work to update my code, so I tried to find another way first....

Comment: @ThomasPerrin it looks like a bug indeed. I have seen many questions from time to time regarding similar issues. But I upvote your question since I believe it is well worth the attention.